# How to evaluate $\log(1 - x)$ in terms of $\log(x)$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I can do this using the following relation:

$$\log(1 - x) = \log(1 - \exp(y))$$

Here $y = \log(x)$ is always a negative number. However, I was wondering whether it's possible to compute $\log(1 - x)$ without using exponentiation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the logarithm of a sum is very tricky business!

Comment: I don't know if it fits into your question, but if you want to calculate the approximate value, use $\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}n$

Comment: @hkmather802 I think you mean $\ln(1 - x) = -\sum^\infty_{n = 1} \frac{x^n}{n}$ because $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: Yeah My mistake.

Comment: @hkmather802 Actually, I wanted to calculate $\log(1 - x)$ using $\log(x)$ because I'm only given $\log(x)$. I could get $x$ using the antilog function but I was wondering if there was a way to compute $\log(1 - x)$ directly from $\log(x)$.

Comment: You should add "Evaluate $\log(1-x)$ in terms of $\log(x)$" in your question then.

Comment: Is it $x-1$ or $1-x $?

Comment: @Ian Thanks for catching that mistake. It's $1 - x$.

Comment: About the best thing that you could say would be something like $\log(1-x)=\log(x)+\log \left ( \frac{1-x}{x} \right )$. This could be useful for approximation purposes perhaps (when $x$ is sufficiently close to $1/2$) but generally it won't be that useful.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-It is true @geodude's comment. Anyway let $f(x)=\log(1-x)$ and $g(x)=\log(x)$. If you make the change of variable $\frac 12+x$ instead of $x$ then you have $f(X)=\log(\frac 12-X)$ and $g(X)=\log(\frac 12+X)$ in which the symmetry of the functions with respect to the line $x= \frac12$ becomes evident and $f(X)=g(-X)\iff f(-X)=g(X)$. Can you use this?

Comment: :/  All your really saying is that if $f(x)=\log(1-x)$ and $g(x)=\log(x)$, then $f(x)=g(1-x)$, or $f(x+1/2)=g(1/2-x)$, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Read the beginning of my COMMENT! and the final question. I did not say it was an answer.